# How do I get to the Forgotten Cell without playing Hide-and-Seek?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I'm playing the Definitive Edition of *Divinity: Original Sin II* on the Switch.  According to the internet, in the elf cave south of Fort Joy, there is a Forgotten Cell here containing an undead knight named Lord Withermoore.  It can be found by playing hide-and-seek with Moby, but I must have selected the wrong option the first time I talked to him (I don't even remember what it was!), because talking to him now gives me no options other than ending the conversation.  It is apparently still possible to find the dirt mound covering the hatch leading to the Forgotten Cell on my own, but I can't find it.

[This image](http://orcz.com/images/2/27/DivinityOriginalSin2AncientStoneHatchMap.jpg) apparently shows the location of the dirt mound, but the only thing there in my game is a hole in the wall, which when interacted with (as Lohse, Sebille, Fane, and the Red Prince) just gives the message "This hole is too small for you to squeeze into."

[This Fandom.com page](https://divinity.fandom.com/wiki/Forgotten_cell) implies that the dirt mound can be found with sufficient Wits.  All of my characters' Wits are currently at 10.  What is the minimum Wits needed to see the dirt mound?  If I have enough Wits, does the dirt mound show up automatically or do I need to do something to trigger a search of the area?

Comment: Note: do no talk to Mody as a Red Prince - he will be scared of you (calling you "the Red Demon") and keep running away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you can discover Withermoore's cell:

You can try talking to Moby with a new character, that should give you a fresh start at interacting with him. Note, however, that not all NPC dialogues reset when talking as a different character, and I'm not sure if Moby is one of them.

If you have a dwarf in your party, they can enter the small hole without any troubles, and uncover the hatch that's hiding the ladder from the inner side.

10 Wits just means the base level, it's not enough to discover most secrets. I believe for this mound you need somewhere around 14 Wits. Failing that, you can go over the spot where the mound is supposed to be, and simply use a shovel. Even if you can't see anything hidden, digging in that spot will reveal the hatch that leads down to Withermoore.

Comment: I was able to get Moby to play hide-and-seek by switching to Sebille, and that led to finding the dirt mound (actually sand).  Thanks!